# Framing a Page from a Holy Book

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, art

Suppose you had a single page from an old Tanakh or rabbinic book. Would it be permissible to frame and mount the page on a wall?

Comment: what is your concern that it shouldn't be ok to do?

Comment: @Dude It might be perceived as disrespectful, especially if it has the name of Hashem. Also, I understand that some will not leave a holy book open, and this is a similar case.

Comment: I don't see how this is like leaving a book open. Not only that but a gram is most often considered to be a form of honor for whatever is put in it bc of the added protection especially if it is a beautiful frame

Answer (score 2):

[During aliyah le'regel](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.54a.11?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) the cohanim would draw back the paroches to show the aron ha'kodesh and say, re'u chibaschem liphnei ha'makom ke'chibas zachar u'nekevah.

See your belovedness before Hashem like the love between a man and a woman.

Given that framing the page shows its endearment and also given that the kedusha of the page is less than that of the aron ha'kodesh it would seem from this mishna that there is no concern about disrespect by making a show of holy judaica.

Comment: Perhaps doing it all the time is different from doing it every few months for a specific purpose?

Comment: (1) Can you bring a cite of a source for what you say in the first paragraph? (2) I find it a little hard to believe that anybody, besides the _Kohanim_ at work there, could see much of anything of the _Aron ha-Berit_, with it being in back of the _Heikhal_, and _Mizbach ha-Olah_ standing between the _Heikhal_ and the _Azarah_ where most male Jews would be standing.

Comment: @TamirEvan I linked the source, and see the ensuing discussion in the gemara to answer your question - the cherubs referred to were those sewn on curtains all around the Temple.