# Framing old Tefillin Parshiot

Tags: halacha, tefilin, art

I recall hearing somewhere that some folks are accustomed to remove the (likely possul) parshiot from old tefillin and [frame them](http://centralgalleries.com/works/large/Jeff%20Framing.jpg).

As tefillin are generally more difficult to correct, is this practice permissible, or at least not prohibited?

---

[CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67802/framing-a-page-from-a-holy-book

Comment: See http://jbfinearts.com/works/large/Tefilin.jpg for an example I do not know if this was done with rabbinic approval.

Comment: I thought you *don't* correct t'fillin but just rewrite them, because they're small and that's not the imposition that it would be for a section of a sefer torah.  (This doesn't affect your main question, just the implication that they could maybe be corrected and reused for their original purpose.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I forget the siman off-hand, but the Keset haSofer (handbook for Ashkenazi sofrim) follows the halacha as brought by the Shulchan Aruch, the Rambam, and the Gemara that tefillin must be written in order. So I can't go back and correct where I misspelled a word two lines earlier, I need to geniza the klaf and start from scratch.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's called "kisidran" (in their order - ke seder [shelh]en) and it applies to tefillin and mezuzot http://stam-ink.blogspot.com/2011/11/stam-bits-kisidran.html

Comment: @MonicaCellio, good tefillin parshiot cost more per wordcount than other sta"m products, due both to the din of kesidran and the small size of the writing. Your average pair of tefillin gassot can cost between $700-$2000 (per set). So you don't want to get a new set of parshiot if there is a chance of fixing them in an affordable manner.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't realize the cost was that high.  I think I might have been mistakingly thinking of mezuzot; I'm pretty sure a local sofer told me that you don't fix those, but they cost a lot less.  (And I assume the writing is larger; I've never seen the contents of tefillin.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, well, with gassot, they take over a year to make the housings. Factor in a high rejection rate (from improperly tanned hides, holes in the leather, et c.) mostly artisan work (no CNC, robot-controlled factory labour) and the cost of certification and you have a fairly expensive product. Add to that thatmany of these factors also apply to the parshiot, as well as other factors (all discussed in Keset haSofer) and you have a fairly expensive product. This website (http://www.mezuzadepot.com) belongs to my sofer and has prices to give you an idea.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67652/759

Answer (score 1):

My sofer (R' Melech Michaels of [MezuzaDepot.com](http://MezuzaDepot.com)) told me over email that keeping old tefillin parshiot and even framing them is permissible.

His rationale was that he knew of no source which forbids this.

Comment: What about אל תשכן באהליך עולה?