May one display possul tefillin parchment in a frame?
Can the parchments of a set of tefillin which have become possul be framed and displayed, or do they need to be buried?

Welcome to MiYodeya Josh and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

I asked someone about this at one point and was told that it's permissible

Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67803/759 @Noach

@DoubleAA, the number of times I remember something and it turns out having been asked and answered here is far from zero
